# USING works but ON failing, why?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sales), 
    date
FROM 
    sales
    INNER JOIN
    exchange_rates
    USING(date)
```

But this fails:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sales), 
    date
FROM 
    sales
    INNER JOIN
    exchange_rates
    ON sales.date = exchange_rates.date
```

Why does this fail -- I thought they were the same? How would I fix the second query?

Comment: How does it "fail"?  Also, show us the table definitions.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for basic posting guidelines.  You have to provide enough information or your question will get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you use the `USING` clause, the column you are joining on does not need to be aliased in the `SELECT` list.  The database knows that the column is not ambiguous-- there is no potential that `sales.date` will be different than `exchange_rates.date`.  If you use the `ON` clause, on the other hand, there is the potential for ambiguity.  Obviously, in this case, you the human knows that there is no ambiguity, it's just that the syntax doesn't guarantee that.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sales), 
    sales.date
FROM 
    sales
    INNER JOIN
    exchange_rates
    ON sales.date = exchange_rates.date
GROUP BY sales.date
```

should work (I'm adding the `GROUP BY` as well just to be explicit)

Answer (score 2):

Try aliasing the Date being called in the actual select statement?

```
SELECT SUM(s.sales), e.date FROM sales s INNER JOIN exchange_rates e ON s.date = e.date
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column for date contains time as well, it is highly unlikely that they'll match in order to JOIN.
Have you tried anything like this?

```
INNER JOIN 
exchange_rates
ON DATE_FORMAT(sales.date,'%c,%e %m) = DATE_FORMAT(exchange_rates.date,'%c,%e %m)
```